# Implemented CSP in my site, but a 3rd party library uses inline javascript. Can I selectively allow 'unsafe-inline'?

Tags: javascript, html, security, web, content-security-policy

I've implemented CSP headers in my public site for security purposes, and have refactored the code to remove any instances of inline javascript like  `onclick=foo()` and `<a href='javascript: bar()'`.

We've recently integrated with a 3rd party that injects code into the page. This is required on every public facing page. The issue is that their code contains a lot of inline javascript (same as mentioned above) and violates our CSP headers that disallow inline scripting.

My understanding is that if you have to add `'unsafe-inline'` for scripting you might as well not implement CSP at all due to the remaining security risks.

We're able to change the CSP headers per page, but since the code is required on every page it seems like it's all or nothing.

It doesn't look like you can allow `'unsafe-inline'` for only specific parts of a page, or we could just allow it for that section.

Is my only choice to allow `'unsafe-inline'` and defeat the whole point of CSP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is my only choice to allow `'unsafe-inline'` and defeat the whole point of CSP?

Most likely, yes. Sorry. But there *might* be a way around it.

If you know exactly what code is going to be injected into your site by the third-party script, you can whitelist that code in your CSP by its hash. For instance, if you knew that the following script would be injected:

```
<script>alert("hello world");</script>
```

you could calculate

```
> Base64(SHA256('alert("hello world");'))
"1tD3lYbOBFeMLrXs+T9Tv9xEgcMsVs032rlMyrYSa0c="
```

and add the following to your CSP:

```
script-src 'sha256-1tD3lYbOBFeMLrXs+T9Tv9xEgcMsVs032rlMyrYSa0c='
```

Of course, this will immensely bloat the size of your policy if multiple inline scripts are involved, and it won't work at all unless the content of those scripts is *absolutely* constant. So whether this is viable will depend significantly on your application, and what script you are trying to maintain compatibility with. (It may even change as that script is updated by the vendor…)

Comment: It should also be noted that not all browsers support the hash method so you normally have to include unsafe-inline AND the sha256 hash. This may sound pointless but those browsers that do support hashing of inline scripts normally explicitly ignore the unsafe-inline part of the policy if a hash is included. And those browsers that don't can continue to use the unsafe-inline. Though Firefox did have a bug where they wouldn't calculate the hash right but did ignore the unsafe-inline part :-( This is fixed now but you might see weirdness like this when using new features like CSP hashes.

Comment: FWIW: Chrome will report the missing or incorrect hash and report the one it calculated instead, saving you from manual generation.

Comment: chrome identifies the hash as an invalid source - using Flask-Talisman for CSP

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [nonce](https://content-security-policy.com/nonce/) method to easily achieve this, without any need for `unsafe-inline`. For example, Google has a [guide on how to integrate Tag Manager](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/web/csp) using the nonce method, which sounds like an example of your use-case.

In short, using this method, the server generates a single-use unpredictable token and sets a CSP to allow it, and then uses the same token for the inline script. This way, the server determines exactly which inline scripts are acceptable.